# JSON Serialization error. Swift conversion error from api response to json

Tags: json, swift, xcode, nsjsonserialization

Data from Server:

```
{"status":{"id":5,"title_en":"Accepted By Restaurant","title_restaurant":"In progress","title_rider":"New","title_customer":"In progress","slug":"accepted_by_restaurant","active":1},"orderDetail":{"id":47,"user_customer_id":27,"user_restaurant_id":13,"user_rider_id":null,"coupon_data":null,"order_status_id":5,"cancelled_by":null,"order_description":"Dsadas","reason_for_cancellation":null,"order_type":"delivery","vat":0,"delivery_fee":0,"total":200,"rider_rating":null,"customer_rating":null,"restaurant_rating":null,"service_rating":null,"reviews":null,"created_at":"2019-11-29 12:38:11","order_status":{"id":5,"title_en":"Accepted By Restaurant","title_restaurant":"In progress","title_rider":"New","title_customer":"In progress","slug":"accepted_by_restaurant","active":1}}}
```

its a valid json I checked on validator.

but its getting invalid json in swift conversion: below is the code:

```
if (JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(dataR!)){
   let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dataR!, options: .prettyPrinted)
   if let response = jsonResponse as? [String: Any]{
```

Comment: If you **receive** data you need `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:options:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method to get Dictionary from json object.

```
    func getDictionaryFromJsonString(dictString:String)-> [String: Any] {
        do {
            return try  JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: 
            dictString.data(using: 
            String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options:  
             JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! Dictionary
        } catch {
            return [:]
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would avoid force unwrapping. There is a reason they return optional values. Unless you're fine with your app to crash don't do that.